# Circular reference exception in json serializer

Tags: json, entity-framework, entity-relationship, jsonserializer

I have a circular object reference which stops an object from being serialized into json. I was trying to use ScriptIgnoreAttribute on the property that is causing problems, but it didn't seem to work. I believe that's because I'm using EF convention with virtual keyword:

```
[ScriptIgnore]
public virtual SomeObject SomeObject { get; set; }
```

The other side of this relationship looks like this

```
public virtual ICollection<OtherObject> OtherObjects { get; set; }
```

I have no additional mappings.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try to use [JsonIgnore] attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each of the `OtherObject` objects has a back reference to `SomeObject`, which in turn has a collection of `OtherObject`, etc.

I would recommend creating a viewmodel class which contains only the properties you need. Then, map your entity to the viewmodel class. Return the viewmodel class instance instead of the raw entity.

The other alternative is to tell the json serializer to stop serializing circular references. I prefer the first approach though.

You can also influence EF behavior (ex. disable lazy loading by removing the `virtual` keyword) or by changing the query.

But really, I prefer the viewmodel approach. I find that using viewmodels solves not only this but other problems as well.

Comment: This seems to be the simplest solution, but is there any other way to resolve this?

Comment: Although OJ Raqueno's answer is definitely the right way to go, especially from the code architecture perspective, I managed to resolve this swapping [ScriptIgnore] attribute with [JsonIgnore]. For whoever will run into similar issue, where refactoring might be a challenge. More on that here http://forums.asp.net/t/1880707.aspx?Excluding+properties+from+serialisation+using+ScriptIgnore+

Comment: @Bartosz I'm glad you found a solution that best fits your particular circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I took the approach of ignoring the associated objects.  To do this you just need to add
`[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]` into your text template (.tt) file.

Here a portion of my text template before

```
#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.NavigationProperty(navigationProperty)#>
<#
```

Once I inserted the code the line above the `codeStringGenerator` my classes auto generated and looked like this:

```
[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]
public virtual ICollection<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
```

I also needed to modify the `UsingDirectives` function to insert `"using System.Web.Script.Serialization;"`